# Force light mode on CupertinoTextField Flutter

Tags: flutter, themes, ios-darkmode, flutter-cupertino

I'm developing a mobile app in Flutter, and until now I only designed a light mode UI and everything is working fine, but if I try to add a `CupertinoTextField`, since my phone is in dark mode it will appear black. Is there an easy way to force it to be light? I wasn't even able to find how to just change its color.

Here's my code:

```
final TextEditingController _textController = TextEditingController();    

CupertinoTextField(
     controller: _textController,
     keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
     minLines: 1,
     maxLines: 5,
     placeholder: 'Type a message'
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the color by adding a `BoxDecoration` in the `CupertinoTextField`

```dart
CupertinoTextField(
          controller: _textController,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
          minLines: 1,
          maxLines: 5,
          placeholder: 'Type a message',
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        )
```